# I want to fix security vulnerability in my docker image

Tags: docker, google-container-registry, cve

I had uploaded a Docker image in Google container Registry. It scanned the image and shows me many vulnerabilities I want to fix atleast critical ones and of high priority so how can I fix it also is there any automatic way of scanning and fixing the docker images for free. I am using the official docker image.

This is the name of image i am using
FROM httpd:latest

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqTAP.png)

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:latest

COPY httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf                   
COPY headerc.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/headerc.conf               
COPY client/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/                              
COPY Cert/server.crt /usr/local/apache2/conf/                        
COPY Cert/server.key /usr/local/apache2/conf/

EXPOSE 443

CMD ["httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

How can i fix the vulnerability issue in docker.

Comment: Have you compared your vulnerabilities to those of your base image?

Answer (score 1):

`httpd:latest` has no CVE (of course!) so I suppose that you are using a very old local copy of that image.
Execute `docker pull httpd:latest` to get really the latest image and rebuild your custom image as usual, or add the `--pull` option to your `docker build` command.